# Getting values only from certain attributes when attributes are in an array

Tags: arrays, xml, r

I think this is a pretty straight forward question, but it's been so frustrating trying to figure out what's going wrong. Here's my input and output while trying to get data from an XML file in R:

```
> stats[1]
[1] "accurate_back_zone_pass"
> xmlValue(getNodeSet(r, "//MatchData/TeamData//MatchPlayer/Stat[@Type = 'accurate_back_zone_pass']")[[1]])
[1] "2"
```

### So that worked!

```
> xmlValue(getNodeSet(r, "//MatchData/TeamData//MatchPlayer/Stat[@Type = stats[1]]")[[1]])
Error in getNodeSet(r, "//MatchData/TeamData//MatchPlayer/Stat[@Type = stats[1]]")[[1]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

### But that doesn't??

The output from the second getNodeSet call is an empty list, but the only difference is that I called the "accurate_back_zone_pass" from an existing array instead of typing in the words manually. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R does not interpret variable names inside quotes.  You should read some introductory R text ([see section 2.6 of R Intro](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf%E2%80%8E), for example).  So in your case, you need to do something like (untested):

```
xmlValue(
  getNodeSet(
    r, 
    paste(
      "//MatchData/TeamData//MatchPlayer/Stat[@Type = ", 
      stats[1]], ")", sep=""
  ) )[[1]]
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to tweak the syntax a bit, but that helped a lot: xmlValue(getNodeSet(r, paste("//MatchData/TeamData//MatchPlayer/Stat[@Type = ","'", stats[1],"'", "]", sep=""))[[1]])